# How can I identify which logged in account called my ASP.Net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

First of all, I know this is not a perfectly fleshed out question. However, I am currently tinkering with my first ASP.net application, and what I created so far is an account management system with login/register functionality as you would expect.

However, now that I finished my registration function (which is selfmade - I'm not sure if this was the best option, but the whole framework is super overwhelming right now), I am wondering what options I have for actually authenticating the current logged in user.

The most obvious solution would be to return a kind of account Id to the javascript frontend which is passed with every call to the backend. However, this can easily be faked by users.

Instead I would like to know if there is any good solution to this in the backend. I know that controllers are regenerated with every call, so storing something there is not possible as well.

I'm sure there must be a way, as I most likely can't be the only one doing this. Do people usually work with the IP of the caller?

Comment: You would have been much better off selecting the `Individual User Accounts` template option. It takes care of all of this

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's what I thought... Do you know if it is possibe to add this after creating the project?

Comment: You could create a new project and copy the stuff over, but that can go wrong easily

Answer (score 0):

**Windows Authentication**

If you use Windows Authentication, all you need to do is put this attribute on your controller (applies to all actions) or on each action and you are good to go:

```
[Authorize]
public class SomeController{}
```

**Forms Authentication**

Here is some code if you are using your own custom authentication form. Actually this is a complete controller so you can just use it.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserReadRepository userReadRepository;
    public AccountController()
    {
        this.userReadRepository = new UserReadRepository();
    }

    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        bool found = this.userReadRepository.Get(model.Email, model.Password) != null;
        if (found)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, false);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (this.userReadRepository != null)
            {
                this.userReadRepository.Dispose();
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        // Just some safety work
        // If the returnUrl is somewhere on our site, go there
        // Otherwise, go to the home page
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Wherever you expect the user to be logged in, put the `[Authorize]` on your action and this is what the framework will do:

1. Is the user logged in?
2. Yes, continue.
3. No, redirect the user to `Login(string returnUrl)` and send the current url to the action. (more about this in step 6).
4. Send the login page to user to fill out.
5. Post the login info to `Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)`
6. If login successful, send the user to the initial location the user wanted to go to.